# Identifying multiple rectangles and draw bounding box around them using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am attempting to draw a bounding box around the two rectangles that are found in the image, but not including the curvy lined 'noise'

[image]

[image]

I have tried multiple methods, including Hough Line Transform and trying to extract coordinates, but to no avail. My methods seemed too arbitrary, and I tried to find the black space between the true rectangles and the noise at the top of the frames but couldn't get a solid general algorithm that could fit that in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so simple to do, you can try to isolate the vertical lines which are quite distinguishable, dilate/erode to make the rectangle a rectangle, and find the contours of what it is left and filter them accordingly... The code would look like:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

minArea = 20 * 20 # area of 20 x 20 pixels

# load image and threshold it
original = cv2.imread("a.png")
img = cv2.cvtColor(original, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thres = cv2.threshold(img, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY )

# Get the vertical lines
verticalStructure = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (1, 10))
vertical = cv2.erode(thres, verticalStructure)
vertical = cv2.dilate(vertical, verticalStructure)

# close holes to make it solid rectangle
kernel = np.ones((45,45),np.uint8)
close = cv2.morphologyEx(vertical, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get contours
im2, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# draw the contours with area bigger than a minimum and that is almost rectangular 
for cnt in contours:
  x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
  area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
  if area > (w*h*.60) and area > minArea:
    original = cv2.rectangle(original, (x,y),(x+w,y+h), (0,0,255), 3)

cv2.imshow("image", original)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And the result is:

[image]

[image]

If it does not work with other images, try adjusting the parameters.

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you! This is certainly not an easy task. If I then wanted to draw a final bounding box around the two rectangles, would the easiest method of doing that be using logic to find coordinates?

Comment: so you want both in one bounding box? you can just put in the same list all the points of the cnt that qualifies. Then find the bounding box with cv2.boundingRect(allPoints) and that's it. you can also put just the corners of the rectangles in a new list and do the bounding box